# image to canvas on chrome but not safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, safari

so here's my problem. I'm making this website in HTML where you can draw your very own self-similar fractal, but here's the thing, it can take the input and process the input, but it can only display the input properly on mac google chrome and mac firefox. safari and Chromebook google chrome both have the issue that the canvas is rendered as too small, smaller than the canvas in firefox and mac google chrome.

```
function update_image(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'fractal.png';
    var canvas = document.getElementById('display');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.style.left = window.screen.width / 2 - (img.width / 2) + "px";
        canvas.style.top = window.screen.height / 4 - (img.height / 2) + "px";
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, img.width, img.height);
                
        imageData.data = editPixels(imageData.data, [img.width, img.height]);
                
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

this is probably the most confusing and weird problem I've run into while programming and helping me out would mean a ton. thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: So logging `img.width` you have different output from different browsers? If so, could you try to save this image using stackoverflow's imgur so we can inspect it. Also, you can't set the `.data` value of an ImageData, so if `editPixels` doesn't modify the buffer in place, the last three lines are useless.

Comment: that's weird because the edit pixels function is like the only thing that does work. but ill try the imgur thing.

Comment: oh my god it worked your amazing i love you