# Why canvas image size break in Safari?

Tags: javascript, canvas

First, the website width and height is based on the user screen.

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
})
```

Then, I am using drawImage

```
class castle {
    constructor() {
        const castle = new Image()
        castle.src = './Img/castle.png'

        castle.onload = () => {
            this.scale = 0.5
            this.image = castle
            this.width = this.image.width * this.scale
            this.height = this.image.height * this.scale
            this.position = {
                x: c.width / 2 - this.width / 2,
                y: c.height / 2 - this.height / 2
            }

            this.center = {
                x: c.width / 2,
                y: c.height / 2
            }
        }

    }

    draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(
            this.image,
            this.position.x,
            this.position.y,
            this.width,
            this.height
        )
    }
}
```

Same monitor:

Why the image shown different size between Google Chrome and Safari?

The performance of my project with Google Chrome is fine.
However, the image size with Safari is too too big

I googled:
[image to canvas on chrome but not safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539887/image-to-canvas-on-chrome-but-not-safari)

Em...
Should I upload all image to imgur? It's better than open a folder Img in my project?

Comment: I'm not sure how the last two questions connect with the rest of your question. For your initial question, different browsers can interpret standards differently. One or both of them might have bugs in their implementation(s).

Comment: I'd start with some debugging: console.log() the various values and look where exactly safari borks.

Answer (score 1):

Safari has issues handling html canvas size. Probably this is why your images are rendering differently.

Canvas size must be: **width * height < 16777216**.

This happened to me a while ago while debugging one of my projects on Safari Mobile.